# Site Provisioning using SharePoint-hosted or Provider-hosted?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, site-template, sharepoint-hosted-app, pnp

I have been reading the [OfficeDevPnP](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP) for best practices on how to create **Site Templates**.

The best practices recommend to use **Remote Provisioning using Provider-Hosted App** to create Custom Sites depending on some configuration.

However, I am wondering, is it possible to do the same using **SharePoint-hosted App**?

I read the difference between them, and it says all business-logic in SharePoint-hosted are only **Javascript.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Hosted App will work on the user and app permission, so its not allowed to created site collection, but you can try to create a powershell to create, and it the creation information is stored in the list then we can schedule the powershell to keeps on reading the list and created based on the provided information.